# Time series data for weather analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series

[image]I have data from 1949 to 2013 (month to month). I am trying to convert it into time series data. But I  get only the data of 1975. The rest of the years are not shown

```
 wt_1 <- xts(wt[,c("Max.Temp","Min.Temp","Rainfall")], order.by=as.Date(wt$YEAR))
```

When I am using Month instead of YEAR

```
 wt_1 <- xts(wt[,c("Max.Temp","Min.Temp","Rainfall")], order.by=as.Date(wt$Month))
```

only the data of 1970 is shown. Other Years data are not shown.

What can I do?

Comment: Please provide some example data e.g. using `dput(head(wt))`